# Automating prompt Submission in Chrome Extension for ChatGPT Page with React JS: Issue with Manual Key Press Requirement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, openai-api, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am currently working on a Chrome extension using React JS and have encountered an issue on ChatGPT page. My extension successfully injects prompt into the ChatGPT textarea element, but I'm facing problem with automating the submission process.

Here's the scenario: The text is successfully added to the textarea, but it doesn't get submitted automatically. The submission only occurs when the i manually presses a key on the keyboard and then clicks on the send button. I am trying to automate this process so that no manual intervention is needed.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { waitForTheElement } from 'wait-for-the-element';

export default function App() {
  const simulateMouseEvent = (element, eventName) => {
    const mouseEvent = new MouseEvent(eventName, {
      view: window,
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true
    });
    element.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let intervalId;

    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations, obs) => {
      const chatGPTTextarea = document.getElementById('prompt-textarea');
      if (chatGPTTextarea) {
        intervalId = setInterval(() => {
          chrome.storage.local.get('chatGPTText', (data) => {
            if (data.chatGPTText && chatGPTTextarea instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement) {
              chatGPTTextarea.value = data.chatGPTText;
              const sendButton = document.querySelector('[data-testid="send-button"]');
              if (sendButton instanceof HTMLButtonElement) {
                sendButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
                simulateMouseEvent(sendButton, 'mousedown');
                simulateMouseEvent(sendButton, 'mouseup');
                simulateMouseEvent(sendButton, 'click');
              }
            }
          });
        }, 2000); // Interval of 2000ms (2 seconds)
      }
    });

    observer.observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true });

    return () => {
      observer.disconnect();
      clearInterval(intervalId); // Clear the interval when the component is unmounted
    };
  }, []);

  return null;
}
```

Comment: Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).